# Singleton list or normal list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and would like to ask some maybe very dumb question about list.

I have some list

```
lst = get_lst()
element = #some element
```

I want to create a single element list [element] or `lst`. I can do it like this

```
result_lst = [element] if element is not None else lst
```

But maybe there is some library function which already does this?

Comment: The expression `[element] if element is not None else lst` looks fine. I wouldn't expect there to be a library function to something like this. It is not a common use case I am aware of.

Comment: That's what you did. @Uriel `is not` is idiomatic in Python for checking if something is not `None`. It's better than "not equal".

Comment: `result_lst = lst if element is None else [element]` saves you a `not` ;)

Comment: @Uriel We are sure.

Comment: @Uriel I'll add that `None` is a singleton object in Python, so you actually are checking for objects being identical. Test `id(None.__class__())` compared to `id(None`)`, or if it's python 2 it will complain you can't create None types.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way to express this might be:

```
result_lst = ([element], lst)[element is None]
```

But I would not necessarily consider it a recommendable pattern or more readable. If the expressions involved get more complex, I'd even drop the ternary operator and use a good old if-else construction.